# Canvas deletes it's self after resizing HTML5/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I made canvas that you can draw on it. And it's also responsive to screen size. But if I resize the browser even with one pixel... Canvas clears it's self. Is there any way to prevent this? Fot the heads up, in my code you'll see code that prevents user from scrolling while he/she is on canvas(drawing). You'll also see code for mobile devices(to make possible for mobile users to draw on canvas). But "scroll prevent" isn't working on `IOS` devices for some reason.

```css
#pen {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#paper {
    display: grid;
    column-count: 1;
}

#canvasORG {
    width: 97.5vw;
    height: 90vh;
    cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='48' viewport='0 0 100 100' style='fill:black;font-size:24px;'><text y='50%'>✍️</text></svg>") 5 27, auto;
}

#colors {
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#black {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
}

#black:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="images/IYN_logo.png" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="paper">
            <div id="canvasORG">
                <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color: white; border:2px solid;"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="colors">
                &emsp;
                <div id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>&nbsp;
                &emsp;
                <button id="pen" style="height: 50px; font-size: 25px; padding-bottom: 5px;">✍</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            const points = [];
            const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, button: false }
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvents);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvents);
            var x = "black",
                y = 5 * 4;
            const canvasORG = document.getElementById("canvasORG");

            (function () {
                window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);
                canvas.width = canvasORG.clientWidth;
                canvas.height = canvasORG.clientHeight;

                function resizeCanvas() {
                    canvas.width = canvasORG.clientWidth;
                    canvas.height = canvasORG.clientHeight;
                    //DRAW ALL
                    //ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                    //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
                }
                resizeCanvas();
            })();

            function mouseEvents(e) {
                mouse.x = e.pageX - 1;
                mouse.y = e.pageY - 1;
                const lb = mouse.button;
                mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
                if (mouse.button) {
                    if (!lb) { points.length = 0 }
                    points.push({ x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y });
                    drawPoints();
                }
            }

            function drawPoints() {
                $(this).scrollTop(0);
                ctx.strokeStyle = x;
                ctx.lineWidth = y;
                ctx.lineCap = "round";
                ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                ctx.beginPath();
                if (mode == "pen") {
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                    for (const p of points) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y); }
                    ctx.stroke();
                } else {
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                    ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            }

            function color(obj) {
                switch (obj.id) {
                    case "black":
                        x = "black";
                        break;
                }
            }

            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
                mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
                var touch = e.touches[0];
                var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
                    clientX: touch.clientX,
                    clientY: touch.clientY
                });
                canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
                var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
                canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
                var touch = e.touches[0];
                var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
                    clientX: touch.clientX,
                    clientY: touch.clientY
                });
                canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
            }, false);

            // Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
            function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
                var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
                return {
                    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
                    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
                };
            }

            document.getElementById("canvas").onwheel = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            };

            document.getElementById("canvas").onmousewheel = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            };

            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })
            canvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })

            var mode = "pen";
            $("#pen").click(function () {
                mode = "pen";
            });
            $("#eraser").click(function () {
                mode = "eraser"
            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code as Code Snippet

Comment: You have a `fillRect()` call in your resize event, that draws over all of your canvas

Comment: Why are you saying clears "itself" - when _you_ are actually actively doing it? `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` - what else did you expect to happen, when you paint a white filled rectangle that covers the full width and height, onto the canvas ...?

Comment: It's still clears it self

Comment: remove `ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`

Comment: Removed it but still clears it.

Comment: Made some changes and added `Code Snippet`

Comment: I don't think you can modify the width/height of a canvas, and expect to keep the current content. You are changing how many pixels the canvas contains - so everything that was on there up to this point, gets thrown away. You need to either use CSS to _stretch_ your existing canvas - or you will need to keep track of all your painting operations, and repeat them after you changed the canvas dimensions.

Comment: Okay but why doesn't scroll lock works on `IOS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the resize handler to redraw the image after the change:

```js
const temp = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
canvas.width = canvasORG.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvasORG.clientHeight;
ctx.putImageData(temp, 0, 0);
```

The problem with this is that if the resize is smaller than the drawing, then the portion that is now off the canvas is destroyed.

```css
#pen {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#paper {
    display: grid;
    column-count: 1;
}

#canvasORG {
    width: 97.5vw;
    height: 90vh;
    cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='48' viewport='0 0 100 100' style='fill:black;font-size:24px;'><text y='50%'>✍️</text></svg>") 5 27, auto;
}

#colors {
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#black {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: black;
}

#black:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="images/IYN_logo.png" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

        <div id="paper">
            <div id="canvasORG">
                <canvas id="canvas" style="background-color: white; border:2px solid;"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="colors">
                &emsp;
                <div id="black" onclick="color(this)"></div>&nbsp;
                &emsp;
                <button id="pen" style="height: 50px; font-size: 25px; padding-bottom: 5px;">✍</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            const points = [];
            const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, button: false }
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvents);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvents);
            var x = "black",
                y = 5 * 4;
            const canvasORG = document.getElementById("canvasORG");

            (function () {
                window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);
                canvas.width = canvasORG.clientWidth;
                canvas.height = canvasORG.clientHeight;

                function resizeCanvas() {
                    const temp = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    canvas.width = canvasORG.clientWidth;
                    canvas.height = canvasORG.clientHeight;
                    ctx.putImageData(temp, 0, 0);
                }
                resizeCanvas();
            })();

            function mouseEvents(e) {
                mouse.x = e.pageX - 1;
                mouse.y = e.pageY - 1;
                const lb = mouse.button;
                mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
                if (mouse.button) {
                    if (!lb) { points.length = 0 }
                    points.push({ x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y });
                    drawPoints();
                }
            }

            function drawPoints() {
                $(this).scrollTop(0);
                ctx.strokeStyle = x;
                ctx.lineWidth = y;
                ctx.lineCap = "round";
                ctx.lineJoin = "round";
                ctx.beginPath();
                if (mode == "pen") {
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                    for (const p of points) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y); }
                    ctx.stroke();
                } else {
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                    ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.fill();
                }
            }

            function color(obj) {
                switch (obj.id) {
                    case "black":
                        x = "black";
                        break;
                }
            }

            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
                mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
                var touch = e.touches[0];
                var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
                    clientX: touch.clientX,
                    clientY: touch.clientY
                });
                canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
                var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
                canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
                var touch = e.touches[0];
                var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
                    clientX: touch.clientX,
                    clientY: touch.clientY
                });
                canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
            }, false);

            // Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
            function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
                var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
                return {
                    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
                    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
                };
            }

            document.getElementById("canvas").onwheel = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            };

            document.getElementById("canvas").onmousewheel = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            };

            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })
            canvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", function (event) { event.preventDefault() })

            var mode = "pen";
            $("#pen").click(function () {
                mode = "pen";
            });
            $("#eraser").click(function () {
                mode = "eraser"
            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```